# Iframe or div in mobile app?

Tags: android, mobile, iframe

I am new to mobile development and am using html and javascript to develop an android+iphone app.Most of the pages in my app require a common header and footer so i was planning to put in all in an Iframe and include it in all pages.However I read that div a better option to do so.Can anyone please elaborate on this?Why is div better?